# Como excluir registro de 2 tabelas sendo que uma contem o 0 a esquerda SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Possuo 2 tabelas em que uma é inserido os registros que vem de um arquivo `txt` e a outra os registros que vem de um arquivo `excel`.

Com isso, preciso excluir os registros da tabela `txt` que contenham na tabela `excel`, no caso os iguais.

Só que existem arquivos na tabela `txt` que começam com 0 e na tabela `excel` não, e o sistema não entende como igual e não exclui.

Como posso fazer para que também exclua os registros que contenham o 0 no começo ?

Meu delete está assim:

```
DELETE 
TEMP_IMPORTACAO_TXT 
FROM 
TEMP_IMPORTACAO_TXT TXT 
INNER JOIN 
TEMP_IMPORTACAO_EXCEL EX 
ON 
TXT.CAMPO = EX.CAMPO
```

Comment: Podem conter, ou não, 1 ou vários 0 a esquerda?

Comment: Como que um campo pode ter zero a esquerda em um banco de dados? O tipo é texto(varchar,car...)?

Comment: Só contem 1 zero a esquerda. @DH.

Comment: @user5978 é varchar o tipo

Comment: Independente da linguagem, quando se tem dois valores representados como string, e você quer fazer uma comparação "numérica" entre esses valores, você deve utilizar um "CAST". o SQLserver implementa isso: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/07/sql-server-convert-text-to-numbers-integer-cast-and-convert/. Sei que já responderão a sua pergunta, mas considere fazer dessa forma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

como não sei que tipo de dados você possui neste campo, pode ser uma string que possua apenas caracteres numericos ou não.

Então você pode usar o substring para remover os zeros a esquerda, por exemplo:

```
DECLARE @texto varchar(max);

SET @texto = '00000001A6F2B';
print SUBSTRING(@texto, PATINDEX('%[^0]%',@texto), LEN(@texto) - PATINDEX('%[^0]%',@texto) + 1)
--1A6F2B
```

o seu select atualizado ficaria assim:

```
DELETE 
TEMP_IMPORTACAO_TXT 
FROM 
TEMP_IMPORTACAO_TXT TXT 
INNER JOIN 
TEMP_IMPORTACAO_EXCEL EX 
ON 
SUBSTRING(TXT.CAMPO, PATINDEX('%[^0]%',TXT.CAMPO), LEN(TXT.CAMPO) - PATINDEX('%[^0]%',TXT.CAMPO) + 1) = EX.CAMPO
```

O unico problema seria caso o campo possua apenas '0', neste caso será preciso fazer uso de um case.

```
CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0]%',@texto) = 0
    THEN '0'
    ELSE SUBSTRING(@texto, PATINDEX('%[^0]%',@texto), LEN(@texto) - PATINDEX('%[^0]%',@texto) + 1)
END
```

Comment: Um CAST seria uma solução melhor.

Comment: @user5978, isto vai depender do conteudo do campo dele, se a mesma possuir alguma caracter não numerico, o cast vai quebrar o script.

Comment: Talvez, mas por ter zero a esquerda, e pelo fato desse zero ter que ser ignorado, acredito que seja uma coluna apenas com números. Na verdade, se for esse o caso, nem CAST é a melhor solução. Deveria mesmo é trocar o tipo da coluna :D